# About python socket UDP

Tags: python

Please, someone, give me a solution
When I want to send a long data like a photo in the socket using ***UDP***
it gives *errno90 message too long*
please someone help me!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjlcY.jpg)

Comment: We need some inforamtion, show us some code

Comment: UDP can send only data up to 65535 bytes (64KB) so isn't very useful for sending large images. Try using TCP.